# Can't find efficient way to replicate original code after refactoring of pandas .resample()

Tags: python, pandas, resampling, deprecation-warning

I am passing a dictionary of pandas DataFrames (or a pandas panel) into the function below in order convert from daily to monthly data.  Each DataFrame represents a field (eg Open, High, Low or Close) in datetime v stock code space.  The function works fine but I am getting deprecation warnings.  I can't find an efficient implementation using the newly refactored resample() though.  Most of the examples I can find use the agg() function to apply different methods to different columns of a single dataframe.  My panel has a separate frame for each field though so this doesn't quite fit.  I've tried using apply(lambda) and it works but is unreasonably slow.  I'm sure there is an efficient implementation for this.  I've noticed several questions that have been answered based on the deprecated implementation and a similar question to mine that has not yet been answered.

Here's my original function:

```
# function to convert daily data to monthly and return dictionary or panel
def to_monthly(fields, data_d, create_panel=True):

    how_dict={'Open':'first', 'High':'max', 'Low':'min', 'Close':'last'}

    data_m={}
    for field in fields:
        data_m[field]=data_d[field].resample(rule='M', how=how_dict[field]).ffill()
    if create_panel:
        data_m = pd.Panel(data_m)

    return data_m
```

This runs fine but I get the deprecation warnings.  My attempt to solve this is:

```
# alternative function to handle refactoring of .resample()
def to_monthly(fields, data_d, create_panel=True):

    how_dict={
        'Open': (lambda x: x[0]),
        'High': (lambda x: x.max()),
        'Low': (lambda x: x.min()),
        'Close': (lambda x: x[-1]),
        'Volume': lambda x: x.sum()
        }

    data_m={}
    for field in fields:
        data_m[field]=data_d[field].resample('M').apply(how_dict[field]).ffill()
    if create_panel:
        data_m = pd.Panel(data_m)

    return data_m
```

I haven't found it easy to locate a replacement syntax for all the old "how" options.  Some assistance on this would also be appreciated.  The Pandas documentation doesn't always seem to provide all the options under a given field or usage.  I've seen others have had similar problems.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Resampler.aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/generated/pandas.tseries.resample.Resampler.aggregate.html) and pass a dict of the Column names as keys with it's respective intended operation as the values.

```
dict_ohlcv = {'Open':'first', 'High':'max', 'Low':'min', 'Close':'last', 'Volume':'sum'}
data_m[field]=data_d[field].resample('M')
                           .agg(dict_ohlcv[field])
                           .ffill()
```

The [`deprecation warnings`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/whatsnew.html#previous-api-will-work-but-with-deprecations) you get is due to the fact that API breaking change to the `.resample` method to make it more `.groupby` like.[*source:* [`Resample API`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/whatsnew.html#resample-api)]

Comment: Thanks for this.  Solves my problem.  I really thought I had tried this already although I may have been confused by the documentation that only provides examples of this type with respect to varying columns fields in a single DataFrame, not different fields across multiple DataFrames

Comment: Unfortunately I was too quick to judge this a solution.  To clarify, the input being passed to data_d is a dictionary of DataFrames, each of which  represents a single field (eg Close) for a list of stocks v datetime index.  So if I pass a dictionary containing just two dataframes (eg Open and Close) with daily data I want it to return a dictionary of 2 dataframes with monthly data.  Applying your methodology here gives each dataframe OHLCV divisions, so multiplies the number of columns in each by 5.